# Detect Slow Internet on iPhone with Monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

In an iPhone/iPad app we would like to enable upload of a picture if the user is on wifi or 3g, but not on edge because it will take way too long. I've seen ways to detect if you're on a carrier network or wifi, but is there a good/simple way of detecting which kind of carrier bandwidth you got, like edge OR 3g? Has anyone tried timing the download/upload of a small sample file to test carrier bandwidth? Is it a good idea to test this or just go with a "cancel upload" button the user can click on if running out of patience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can only detect what network type user uses: wifi or 3g/edge (here is [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)). If you want to detect the actual speed you'll need to test actual connection by hand.
As for me it is beter to provide "cancel upload" button and do not hurt users with slow internet.

Answer (score 1):

People can drop from 3G to EDGE just as they have tapped to start uploading, or gain 3G, LTE or Wi-Fi coverage just after deciding not to upload. In the real world, the bandwidth can remain stable, yes, but it can also change a dozen times in a few minutes when you're on the move.

I think you would be better served by just allowing the picture upload in any case, informing the user if the upload is slow and letting them cancel at any time. If the model permits it, you could let the image upload run in the background and come in late.